# how to groupby pandas dataframe on some condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like following

```
buyer_id item_id order_id        date
   139      57      387     2015-12-28
   140       9      388     2015-12-28
   140      57      389     2015-12-28
   36        9      390     2015-12-28
   64       49      404     2015-12-29
   146      49      405     2015-12-29
   81       49      406     2015-12-29
   140      80      407     2015-12-30
   139      81      408     2015-12-30
```

There are lot of rows in above dataframe. What I am trying to achieve is, whether introducing new dishes driving my users to come back. `item_id` is mapped to a dish name. What I want to see is if a specific user is ordering different dish on different day. 
e.g `buyer_id 140 has ordered two dishes item_id (9,57) on 28th Dec and same buyer has ordered different dish (item_id = 80) on 30th Dec` 
Then I want to flag this user as `1`

How I am doing it in python is like this

```
item_wise_order.groupby(['date','buyer_id'])['item_id'].apply(lambda x:    
x.tolist())
```

it gives me following output

```
date        buyer_id
2015-12-28  139                 [57]
            140                 [9,57]     
            36                  [9]
2015-12-29  64                  [49]
            146                 [49]
            81                  [49]
2015-12-30  140                 [80]
            139                 [81]
```

Desired output

```
 buyer_id item_id order_id        date    flag
   139      57      387     2015-12-28     1
   140       9      388     2015-12-28     1
   140      57      389     2015-12-28     1
   36        9      390     2015-12-28     0
   64       49      404     2015-12-29     0 
   146      49      405     2015-12-29     0
   81       49      406     2015-12-29     0
   140      80      407     2015-12-30     1
   139      81      408     2015-12-30     1
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov  I have edited the question

Comment: Why is your flag for first row in the expected output isn't 1?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov Ohh sorry that should be 1.. my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Anton's answer, but using apply

```
users = df.groupby('buyer_id').apply(lambda r: r['item_id'].unique().shape[0] > 1 and 
                                               r['date'].unique().shape[0] > 1 )*1
df.set_index('buyer_id', inplace=True)
df['good_user'] = users
```

result:

```
          item_id  order_id        date  good_user
buyer_id
139            57       387  2015-12-28          1
140             9       388  2015-12-28          1
140            57       389  2015-12-28          1
36              9       390  2015-12-28          0
64             49       404  2015-12-29          0
146            49       405  2015-12-29          0
81             49       406  2015-12-29          0
140            80       407  2015-12-30          1
139            81       408  2015-12-30          1
```

**EDIT** because I thought of another case: suppose the data shows a buyer buys the same two (or more) goods on two different days. Should this user be flagged as 1 or 0? Because effectively, he/she does not actually choose anything different on the second date.
So take buyer 81 in the following table. You see they only buy 49 and 50 on both dates.

```
    buyer_id   item_id order_id    date
         139        57      387    2015-12-28
         140         9      388    2015-12-28
         140        57      389    2015-12-28
          36         9      390    2015-12-28
          64        49      404    2015-12-29
         146        49      405    2015-12-29
          81        49      406    2015-12-29
         140        80      407    2015-12-30
         139        81      408    2015-12-30
          81        50      406    2015-12-29
          81        49      999    2015-12-30
          81        50      999    2015-12-30
```

To accomodate this, here's what I came up with (kinda ugly but should work)

```
# this function is applied to all buyers
def find_good_buyers(buyer):
    # which dates the buyer has made a purchase
    buyer_dates = buyer.groupby('date')
    # a string representing the unique items purchased at each date
    items_on_date = buyer_dates.agg({'item_id': lambda x: '-'.join(x.unique())})
    # if there is more than 1 combination of item_id, then it means that
    # the buyer has purchased different things in different dates
    # so this buyer must be flagged to 1
    good_buyer = (len(items_on_date.groupby('item_id').groups) > 1) * 1
    return good_buyer


df['item_id'] = df['item_id'].astype('S')
buyers = df.groupby('buyer_id') 

good_buyer = buyers.apply(find_good_buyers)
df.set_index('buyer_id', inplace=True)
df['good_buyer'] = good_buyer
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

This works on buyer 81 setting it to 0 because once you group by date, both dates at which a purchase was made will have the same "49-50" combination of items purchased, hence the number of combinations = 1 and the buyer will be flagged 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But, the flag should set to true only when there are different `item_id` on different dates

Comment: How would I set a flag to `0 & 1` I don't want to set index as `buyer_id`

Comment: I updated the answer to get the 0 and 1. (just multiply the boolean column by 1 to force it to 0/1)
the condition for 1 is that there be more than 2 items bought in more than 2 dates. i.e. it cannot be set to 1 if a buyer appears only in 1 date OR if a buyer buys only one thing. how does this not cover your scenario? the data you have shown here doesn't show other cases

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. really appriciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You could groupby by `buyer_id`, then aggregate column with `np.unique`. Then you'll get `np.ndarrays` for rows where you have several dates and item_ids. You could find that rows with `isinstance` of `np.ndarray` and you'll get bool series which you could pass to aggregated dataframe and find interested buyer. By filtering original dataframe with obtained `buyers` you could fill rows for `flag` with `loc`:

```
df_agg = df.groupby('buyer_id')[['date', 'item_id']].agg(np.unique)
df_agg = df_agg.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, np.ndarray))

buyers = df_agg[(df_agg['date']) & (df_agg['item_id'])].index
mask = df['buyer_id'].isin(buyers)

df['flag'] = 0
df.loc[mask, 'flag'] = 1

In [124]: df
Out[124]: 
   buyer_id  item_id  order_id        date  flag
0       139       57       387  2015-12-28     1
1       140        9       388  2015-12-28     1
2       140       57       389  2015-12-28     1
3        36        9       390  2015-12-28     0
4        64       49       404  2015-12-29     0
5       146       49       405  2015-12-29     0
6        81       49       406  2015-12-29     0
7       140       80       407  2015-12-30     1
8       139       81       408  2015-12-30     1
```

Output from first and second steps:

```
In [146]: df.groupby('buyer_id')[['date', 'item_id']].agg(np.unique)
Out[146]: 
                              date      item_id
buyer_id                                       
36                      2015-12-28            9
64                      2015-12-29           49
81                      2015-12-29           49
139       [2015-12-28, 2015-12-30]     [57, 81]
140       [2015-12-28, 2015-12-30]  [9, 57, 80]
146                     2015-12-29           49

In [148]: df_agg.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, np.ndarray))
Out[148]: 
           date item_id
buyer_id               
36        False   False
64        False   False
81        False   False
139        True    True
140        True    True
146       False   False
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer.. Appriciated :)

Comment: Where are you checking the condition in the code for different `item_id` ?

Comment: @Neil when used `agg` with `np.unique`. If there are more then one unique `item_id` then it'll be `np.ndarray` which will give `True` for `isinstance(x, np.ndarray)`